# Finding Sampling Rate Of Touch Screen In Android

Tags: android

Is there a way to find out sampling rate of the touch screen in an Android device ?

I tried this stackoverflow post but did not help my exact requirement
[Adjust touch input sample rate on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6746127/adjust-touch-input-sample-rate-on-android).

Answer (score 0):

If you're interested in measuring the sample rate from the command-line, you can get some information using:

```
adb shell getevent
```